# Convert canvas coordinate system to OpenGLES 2.0 coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas, coordinate-transformation

I started drawing hexagonal grid on canvas with Path object. I did all the calculations on how many hexagons go on a particular display, depending on the hexagon size.

I have all my hexagon coordinates calculated depending on canvas. But now, I have serious performance issues and have to port this to OpenGL.

Because the algorithm works in canvas, I'm trying to convert those "canvas" hexagon coordinates to OpenGL coordinate system with GLU.gluUnProject.

"for loop"

```
float near[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
            GLU.gluUnProject(b.hexes[ii][jj].points[ii].x,
                    b.hexes[ii][jj].points[ii].y, 0, mg.mModelView, 0,
                    mg.mProjection, 0, viewport, 0, near, 0);
vertices[zz] = (float) ((near[0])/near[3]);
            zz++;
            vertices[zz] = (float) ((near[1])/near[3]);
            zz++;
            vertices[zz] = 0;
```

Because I lack opengl knowledge, I dont know how to set glViewport,gluPerspective,glTranslatef to 2D world that is "the same" as canvas.

So my question is:

How to set those three thing that my first hexagon (**on canvas, the first one is top left**) to be equal on openGL drawing surface world?

**Update**

Thank you all for you're interest of helping on my problem. But:

I now set my 18 float vertices array as follows:
[20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 34.641018, 0.0, 60.0, 69.282036, 0.0, 20.0, 69.282036, 0.0, 0.0, 34.641018, 0.0]
**Z is always 0.**

```
ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer
                .allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexBuffer = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

**and draw:**

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length/3);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

**Before draw I set:
onDrawFrame()**

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
```

**onSurfaceChanged()**

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: gluUnProject seems like the wrong way to go here. If you just want to port straight from canvas coordinate system to OpenGL, you know that you can set opengl coordinate system to be whatever you want it to be? You should be able to use the same coordinates in OpenGL without a problem. Can you give an example of what kind of canvas coordinates you're working with, and would like to replicate?

Comment: Ok, hexagon is made out of 6 x,y coordinates, this are the top left hex coordinates:

"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].x" 20.0 
"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].y" 0.0


"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].x" 60.0 
"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].y" 0.0 


"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].x" 80.0 
"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].y" 34.641018 


"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].x" 60.0 
"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].y" 69.282036 


"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].x" 20.0 
"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].y" 69.282036 


"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].x" 0.0 
"b.hexes[0][0].points[ii].y" 34.641018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to transform yourself the vertices coordinates. All you have to do is to provide the correct projection matrix to OpenGL.

Basically, this would be something along the lines of :

```
glViewport(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                     // or some matrix uniform if using shaders
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, 0, -1, 1); // this will allow to pass vertices in 'canvas pixel' coordinates
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Depending on the order in which you're passing your vertices, you might want to make that culling is disabled.

Comment: While I agree with your general proposal, note that the OP mentions OpenGLES **2.0**, for which none of these functions exist. This may be confusing if he has not used the deprecated functions before.

Comment: I got confused by the OP mentionning `glTranslatef`. Problem with OpenGL ES 2 is that without any standard math library around, its difficult to give synthetic code snippets.

Comment: With my code above, I only had to fix this line:

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length/3);

Now it is working great! Thank you all!

rotoglup, I marked your answer.